# Mismatch in SQLite for node deployment to azure

Tags: node.js, azure, sqlite, azure-web-app-service

## Background

I am deploying a node.js web app from local git. [Like in the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git). I have successfully deployed the hello-world sample, and that worked.

Now I want to deploy another version of the app - which has a lot of new features and dependencies. The `package.json` contains among other

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.1"
},
"dependencies": {
    "jsonschema": "^1.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "npm": "^5.8.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.0"
}
```

My local developer environment is

```
PS ...> node --version
v9.8.0
PS ...> npm --version
5.8.0
```

And I have present in my repo `.\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v59-win32-x64`.
This works great locally!

### The Problem

This time when I deploy to Azure, it doesn't work as well as before. When doing the `git push azure-prod master` I get a warn:

```
Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
remote: .......................................
remote: npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\6.9.1\node.exe but npm is using D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.10.0\node.exe itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
remote:
remote: > sqlite3@4.0.0 install D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3
remote: > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote: [sqlite3] Success: "D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node" is installed via remote
```

And trying to access the web app generates a HTTP 500. The application log on Azure says

```
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v57-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

### The question

How do I deploy sqlite3 with nodejs to Azure Web Apps correctly?

### Related questions

http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2014/02/07/Why-is-a-32bit-Windows-Azure-WebSite-running-as-64bit/ Discuss a similar problem, but is related to mismatching architecture (32 vs 64-bit). It also uses the kudu console to patch the installation after deploy - which to me seems like a suboptimal fix. Is there a more robust solution?

Comment: I am troubleshooting the node/npm versions. There seems to be some versioning mismatch between what node environments are available to Azure Web Apps, and what node/npm versions are available through the local git deploy option. Currently downgrading to Node 8.10.0...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about nodejs and npm versions mismatch between my developing environment, the deploy environment and the runtime environment. So I resolved it in three steps:

### 1. Find a possible node.js version

During `git push azure-prod master`, I got the information:

```
remote: Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.10.40, 0.12.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3 ...
```

I chose a node version from that list. The newest version was `8.10.0`.

### 2. Find a corresponding npm version

I went to `https://<my-site>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/diagnostics/runtime` and got the list of what npm version that matched this. The matching version was `5.6.0`.

### 3. Fix the `package.json`

I wrote

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8.10.0",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
}
```

in my `package.json`

### 4. Configure Aure

Though probably unneccessary, I chose `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to be `8.10.0`.

### 5. Deploy

A final `git push azure-prod master` got the whole thing up and running!